# $PYTHONPATH and sys.path don't seems to match

Tags: debian, python, python3

I want to add a folder permanently to `sys.path` but it doesn't work.

On my Debian Stretch, when I execute :

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
```

it looks empty

In the same time, when I print the content of `sys.path`, there is 10 different paths which aren't the same than those contained into `$PATH` (and obviously in `$PYTHONPATH`). How can it be explained ?

(I had to create a virtualenv for a framework but I don't think I'm using it right now so it's probably not related but I'm not confortable with that concept so maybe I miss something)

Also I've tried to modify `.bashrc` to add a path to `$PYTHONPATH` so I've know the following line :

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/bin
```

After rebooting, it works, I mean $PYTHONPATH contains it but nothing change for `sys.path`.

Also, `$ env | grep ^PYTHON` returns nothing.

So, how `sys.path` is filled and how can I add permanently a folder to it ?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` has nothing to do with each other. `PYTHONPATH` is where `python` looks for modules. `sys.path` is initialized by `python` and may be further modified by modules and the main script. What is the issue that you are experiencing?

Comment: I know that there aren't related but, in the same time, I can't figure out where that list of folder comes from. I thought I was clear about the issue, I can't add a folder to sys.path by modifying $PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Did you `export PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sys.path` in Python is a "list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, plus an installation-dependent default." (taken from [the Python online documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)).

For `sys.path` to be affected by `PYTHONPATH`, the latter has to be an environment variable. If it's not an environment variable but just a shell variable, it will not be visible by the `python` interpreter. You turn it into an environment variable by exporting it after setting its value, or at the same time, as in

```
export PYTHONPATH=/some/path:/goes/here
```

Comment: By the way, since my PYTHONPATH was empty of have you an idea, how does the other folders paths were determined ?

Comment: @snoobdogg It's dependent on the installation of Python.  For a slightly longer explanation, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38403654/931027